# Clicking "NoFilter" in Telerik DetailTables does not remove expression from TextBox

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

In this case, there is absolutely no problem with the actual filtering, however, a cosmetic bug exists in which the expression is not removed from the textbox.

There is a   within the RadGrid. Both Master and Detail tables have filtering enabled and it works perfectly fine. When I try to remove the filterexpression at the DetailTable level (using the 'nofilter') menu option, the filter expression still persists in the textbox. How can I remove this? What code can I write to identity if the filtering request happened from mastertable or detailtable? In the end, I just want the text from the filter textbox to disappear.

Sample code:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="SomeGridView" runat="server">
<ClientSettings>
    <ClientEvents OnFilterMenuShowing="FilterMenuShowing" />
</ClientSettings>
<Columns>
</Columns>
<DetailTables>
    <telerik:GridTableView Name="Details">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FieldName" HeaderText="Some Header" SortExpression="FieldName" UniqueName="FieldName" />
        </Columns>
    </telerik:GridTableView>
</DetailTables>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I resolved my own question.
But I find this extra effort was not needed for the MasterTableView filters, since it automatically cleared the textbox values when I selected "NoFilter".
Is this a known Telerik bug? 
You can follow the ticket here:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/clear-filter-expresssion-text-box-in-radgrid#me_BRg3iXUOgDucx47Wigg

```
    protected void RadGridView_DetailTableDataBind(object sender, GridDetailTableDataBindEventArgs e)
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = e.DetailTableView.ParentItem;

        if (IsPostBack == true)
        {
            foreach (GridColumn thisColumn in e.DetailTableView.Columns)
            {
                if (thisColumn.CurrentFilterFunction == GridKnownFunction.NoFilter)
                {
                    thisColumn.CurrentFilterValue = string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```